# Traffic towards Google API server to Internal VMs are supported by Private Google Access or not

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-networking

I have a GCE VM without external IP but Private Google Access enabled for that subnet where this VM deployed. Hence this VM can access Google APIs without external IP but does the Google API's will be able to find the VM's IP or hostname to post / get the data via HTTP/HTTPS.

The service account which we used to create this GCE VM has access to Google cloud service API(ex: cloud functions API) from which it expecting the data / API request.

So the questions is ,
Traffic towards Google API server to Internal VMs are supported by Private Google Access or not .

Answer (score 1):

Just found this feature from Google cloud that is Serverless VPC access, it solves this issue and it enables cloud function or any serverless environments to access Compute Engine VM instances and any other resources with an internal IP address .

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Answer (score 0):

Yes, traffic towards Google API server to Internal VMs are supported by Private Google Access. By default, when a Compute Engine VM lacks an external IP address assigned to its network interface, it can only send packets to other internal IP address destinations. You can allow these VMs to connect to the set of external IP addresses used by Google APIs and services by enabling Private Google Access on the subnet used by the VM's network interface. Keep in mind Private Google Access has the following [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#requirements)

Comment: No Lukas, I think private google access is only for allowing traffic from VMs to Google APIs ,, Not from Google APIs to Internal VMs. Because I have cloud function which is trying to post the data on the application running on internal VM but it failed with address not found error.

Comment: are you sure the cloud function is in the same VPC are GCE instance? are you sure the firewall settings allow this traffic? Also you might have to create route manually [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config-routing)

Comment: I had the firewall rules in place for egress & ingress with source and destination of 0.0.0.0/0 but didn't have any custom routes . In this case , what is the difference between these two services  - Serverless VPC access & Private Google access .